# How to Send latest attachment using Jenkins in Email?

Tags: jenkins, ant

I'm creating Automation xlsx file with Timestamp and in jenkins edit email attachment saying as use Ant patterns to send attachment,I've used below pattern but it is sending all xlsx files which are in that folder.

Format : **/Screenshots/*.xlsx

But i need only latest saved file.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. Can you save the xlsx file into a second directory? Use Jenkins to clear the directory first, before the latest is created, then you can just send the contents of that directory.

Comment: Please Send me the steps to clear the directory in workspace and copy file in workspace directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Filesystem List Parameter' Plug-in in Jenkins, which can be useful for your question. refer to link for reference-
[Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Filesystem+List+Parameter+Plug-in)

Comment: Chandra,Can you please provide proper steps to configure in jenkins

Comment: If you want Delete the workspace -
In Build Environment in Job Configuration,Check the 'Delete workspace before build starts' option

Comment: Hi Chandra,Please send me proper steps and what need to select and how to enter proper data in File System List Parameter and How to Configure to pick up latest file in Jenkins and my file name displays in this format testcases_results_ddmmyyyy_hh_mm_ss.xlsx

Comment: I've installed Plugin and what are the steps and where it will display the plugin ,i'm not able to see plugin in post build action in job configuration screen